# Scripting the Keyframe Inserts for Opacity and Volume

Tags: python, blender

Having added, trimmed and arranged my home video recordings within the `Video Sequence Editor` under Blender 2.74. My next goal is to automate the fading in and fading out, with script, each audio and video sequence.

At the moment my script loops though all the sequences and checks the type. If the sequences type is movie or image the opacity is to be keyframed and if the sequences is sound, than the volume is to be keyframed. Currently my script also has the ability to find the start and end frame for each sequence, as well as the ability to calculate and jump to the frame where the fading should start/end. However, to keyframe the opacity and the volume inside the `Graph Editor` with script, dose not appears to be possible.

According to the Blender 2.73.8 API, there appears to be the ability to script keyframing with `bpy.ops.graph.keyframe_insert(type='ALL')`, but there dose not appear to be any ability to keyframe the opacity nor the volume with scripting.

Can someone show me how to keyframe the opacity and volume using script?

```
import bpy



# ----------------------------------------
# main
# ----------------------------------------

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.frame_current = 0

queue = scene.sequence_editor.sequences

print("Frames Per Second [ ", scene.render.fps, " ].")
bpy.ops.sequencer.select_all(0)

for i in queue:
    itemLead = i.frame_start
    itemBack = itemLead + i.frame_final_duration

    print("Lead [ ", itemLead, " ] Tail [ ", itemBack, " ].")
    itemType = i.type

    if itemType == "MOVIE":
        i.select = 1

        scene.frame_current = itemLead
        i.blend_alpha = 0.0

        ##bpy.ops.graph.keyframe_insert(type="blend_alpha")

        print("Movie mode.")
        i.select = 0

        continue

    if itemType == "SOUND":
        i.select = 1
        print("Sound mode.")
        i.select = 0

        continue

    if itemType == "IMAGE":
        i.select = 1
        print("Image mode.")
        i.select = 0

        continue

    print("Skipped [ ", itemType, " ].")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a keyframe using python you tell the owner of the property (the strip) to [insert a keyframe](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) for one of it's properties (the opacity)

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
queue = scene.sequence_editor.sequences

queue[0].blend_alpha = 0.0
queue[0].keyframe_insert('blend_alpha', frame=1)

queue[0].blend_alpha = 1.0
queue[0].keyframe_insert('blend_alpha', frame=10)
```

You may also notice that you can specify the frame for the key, so that you don't need to adjust the current frame. If you do want to alter the current frame it is better to use [`scene.frame_set()`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set).

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much. I seen now why the API says "path to the property to key" under the section keyframe_insert(), that word "path" is little misleading, it should simply say "the property to key". I will be posting the final version of my code below to assist anyone who is interested.

Comment: For many cases it is just the property name, but it is possible to get longer paths, see the example for a bone with custom properties - `data_path=bones["Bone"].my_prop.nested`

Comment: Got it! So that explains that word "path".

Comment: @sambler mustn't be the data_path arg be a string? As in `data_path='bones["Bone"].my_prop.nested'`?

Comment: @TNT It is - `'blend_alpha'` is the `data_path` - the example is applying keyframes to a property of a VSE strip, the strip contains the property so the longer armature style path with the bone name is not needed. With armatures as the armature object holds all of the animation data for it's bones you need a path that includes which bone it is for.

Comment: @sambler Well, despite I'm not understanding what `bones["Bone"].my_prop.nested` exactly is, I think it could e.g. be called as keyword-arg like `queue[0].keyframe_insert(data_path='blend_alpha', frame=1)`. So in your comment that `data_path=bones["Bone"].my_prop.nested` would be more real live code if written as `data_path='bones["Bone"].my_prop.nested'`, wouldn't it? Or could it also be a reference as you wrote it?

Comment: @TNT not every little item contains animation data. The data_path is the path from the item with animation data to the value being animated.  An armature is the parent of multiple bones, the bone name is then needed to know which bone the animation is for. Asking a question can provide a more detailed answer. Would be better to ask that one at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

See below for the final version of my code:

```
import bpy



# ----------------------------------------
# main
# ----------------------------------------

scene = bpy.context.scene
queue = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
depth = scene.render.fps * 1.8

for i in queue:

    itemType = i.type
    itemLead = i.frame_offset_start + i.frame_start
    itemHind = itemLead + i.frame_final_duration

    if itemType == "MOVIE":

        i.blend_alpha = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemLead)

        i.blend_alpha = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemLead + depth)

        i.blend_alpha = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemHind - depth)

        i.blend_alpha = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemHind)

        continue

    if itemType == "SOUND":

        i.volume = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="volume", frame=itemLead)

        i.volume = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="volume", frame=itemLead + depth)

        i.volume = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="volume", frame=itemHind - depth)

        i.volume = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="volume", frame=itemHind)

        continue

    if itemType == "IMAGE":

        i.blend_alpha = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemLead)

        i.blend_alpha = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemLead + depth)

        i.blend_alpha = 1.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemHind - depth)

        i.blend_alpha = 0.0
        i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemHind)

        continue
```

Comment: You can streamline by not adding the keyframes sequentially, e.g.: 

`i.blend_alpha = 0.0
i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemLead)
i.keyframe_insert(data_path="blend_alpha", frame=itemHind)`